# Error Message ! LaTeX Error: File `mathdesign.sty' not found

Tags: packages

I am new to Latex and keep getting the same error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mathdesign.sty' not found.
```

This error message appears even when the line is deactivated (?) using %.
The line that the error message corresponds to is:

```
%\tuprints{12345}{id/eprint/1234}
```

Thank you for your help in advance!
:)

Comment: the error will come from `\usepackage{mathdesign}` (or `\RequirePackage{mathdesign}` it seems unlikely that `\tuprints` is the cause although as that isn't a standard command and you do not give its definition it is hard to guess. Show a small but complete document that shows this error.

Comment: line numbers don't necessarly refer to the main file. Check in the log which file is read when you get the error.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error when compiling a file containing `\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}`. I searched for `mathdesign` in the Synaptic Package Manager and the only result was `texlive-fonts-extra`.

Installing the package `texlive-fonts-extra` fixed the issue for me.